# Discordのbotで画像を送信したい

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

題名の通り、Discordのbotで画像付きで送信したいです。
discord.jsを使っています。
↓ここのを参考にしましたが上手くいきません。
https://weakenedfuntimeblog.wordpress.com/2017/07/23/bot%E3%81%A7%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%82%92%E9%80%81%E3%82%8B/

```
bot.createMessage(msg.channel.id, {files: ["test.png"]});
```

こんな感じのコードで書いてるんですが何が間違っているのかわかりません。
教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: コーディングスタイルが違うように見えるので、参考になるとしたら [Node.jsでユーザ動作に反応するDiscordのBotを作ってみた](https://qiita.com/sbhr/items/43320a828e62eadbd77a) かもしれません。 元の参考にしたサイトに合わせるなら、こちら [Discord.jsで簡単にbotを作成する【基礎編】](https://qiita.com/misskotocoin/items/5d8c503e02093eca1f9b) あたりではないでしょうか？

Comment: コーディングは多分あってると思います。質問したかった部分は{files: ["test.png"]}の所です。わかりにくくてすみません…。

Comment: やはり使い方がまちがっているのでは？ bot.createMessage()というのはErisというDiscordのためのNode.js用Wrapperの関数ですね。参考サイトはDiscord.jsを直接使っているように見えるので、両者が噛み合わないのでしょう。bot.createMessage()を使いたいなら、Erisの使い方を解説している記事を探してください。

Comment: Eris 0.9.0 の [createMessage](https://abal.moe/Eris/docs/Client#function-createMessage) の説明によると、こういう風に書けるのでは？ `bot.createMessage(msg.channel.id, 'xxxx', { name: "test.png" });`

Comment: 確かに書き方が違いますね。しかし後ろの部分の設定がよくわかんないですね…。fileって言われても何をすればいいのか…。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{ file: { attachment: test} }`を使う場合、erisでは無理で、discord.jsを用いたものでないと出来ません。`message.channel.send("message",{ file: { attachment: test} });`という使い方をします。

Comment: 推測ですが、erisではアプリ自身でファイルをBufferクラスオブジェクトに読み込んで、createMessageの第3パラメータに指定するのだと思われます。discord直接のようにファイル名だけ指定すれば良いというのでは無いのでしょう。